# Accessing unknown Json structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I need to access a json object in javascript with the following strucure:

```
jsonp1354291250080({
    "query":{"count":"1","created":"2012","lang":"en"},
    "results":["this is a test"]
});
```

I'm receiving this object from an online service, I cannot control its structure and using `data.query` is not working.

Please if someone knows how to access it.

UPDATE: I'm using jquery.xdomainajax.js of James Padolsey https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/
and using $.get() function of jQuery to do cross-domain requests

Comment: That does'nt look to be valid .. anything? What is `jsonp1354291250080`

Comment: @adeneo: Looks like a JSONP response.

Comment: it's what I'm receiving, jsonp1354291250080 is changing with each new request. That's what I see in the "Response" tab of FireBug

Comment: @user1689607 - well, duh! But it does'nt look like that, there's either an object or a callback in there somewhere, but what is what ?

Comment: @BakrKawkji: The API probably gives you the ability to set your own function name.

Comment: @adeneo: That's how a JSONP response looks.

Comment: @user1689607 can you please tell me how to parse it if it's JSONP?

Comment: @BakrKawkji - Have no idea, I'm guessing `jsonp1354291250080` is the callback function needed? user1689607 has obviously seen this before and probably knows how to work with it.

Comment: @BakrKawkji, you don't need to use jquery.xdomainajax.js to do crossdomain requests. jQuery handles this for you with `$.get` and `$.getJSON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a [JSONP](http://json-p.org/) service since you are on a different domain. Your best bet is to let [jQuery's $.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) handle it for you.

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by
>   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the
>   discussion of the jsonp data type in [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

The JSONP example on that page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="images">

  </div>
<script>
  $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
    {
      tags: "mount rainier",
      tagmode: "any",
      format: "json"
    },
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
        if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```